# Automatically updating a tkinter label that isn't directly accessible

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter

I want to create a simple GUI for a constant data that comes through Serial. I decided to use tkinter. The value `reading` is updated and should be shown in a label. I created separate classes for the container and the other pages. I defined the container as such:

```
class Gui(Tk):
def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    Tk.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
    container = Frame(self)
    container.pack(side="top", fill = "both", expand = TRUE)
    container.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight = 1)

    self.frames={}

    for F in (StartPage, PageOne):
        frame = F(container, self)
        self.frames[F] = frame
        frame.grid(row = 0, column = 0, sticky = "nsew")
        frame.UpdateMe()

    self.show_frame(StartPage)


def show_frame(self, cont):
    frame = self.frames[cont]
    frame.tkraise()
```

And the page showing the label:

```
class PageOne(Frame):
def __init__(self, parent, controller):
    Frame.__init__(self,parent)
    global reading
    self.label1text = StringVar()
    self.label1 = Label(self, textvariable = label1text)
    self.label1.pack()
    button1 = Button (self, text = "Show Start Page", command = lambda: controller.show_frame(StartPage))
    button1.pack()
    self.label1text.set(reading)


def UpdateMe(self):
    global reading
    self.lable1text.set(reading)
```

Now, to initialize the GUI:

```
root = Gui()
root.mainloop()
```

However, since `mainloop()` is blocking, any argument coming after that wouldn't be executed; I could get around that with `update` and `update_idletasks`. However, I still don't know how I could call the function `UpdateMe()` inside `PageOne()`when I only created an instantiation of the `Gui()`. Is there a way for me to solve this or remediate my understanding of classes and object programming?

Comment: Can you make `reading` a `StringVar` and use it as the `textvariable` of `self.label1`?  Then whenever `reading` is updated, the label will be updated as well and no need to call `frame.UpdateMe()`.

Comment: I tried doing  what you've recommended. The window would show but the label would be blank. I've verified that the value of reading is changing by using another thread.

Comment: Can you update your question with your changes so far?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you cannot create `StringVar` without initializing `Tk()` (for your case, it is `Gui()`), so you need to create the `reading` variable inside `Gui()` and `PageOne.label1` uses it as its `textvariable`.  Below is an example based on your code:

```
from tkinter import *
from random import randint

class Gui(Tk):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        Tk.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
        container = Frame(self)
        container.pack(side="top", fill="both", expand=True)
        container.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
        container.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)

        self.reading = StringVar() # create the StringVar for PageOne

        self.frames = {}
        for F in (StartPage, PageOne):
            frame = F(container, self)
            frame.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="nsew")
            self.frames[F] = frame
        self.show_frame(StartPage)

    def show_frame(self, cont):
        self.frames[cont].tkraise()

class StartPage(Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        button1 = Button (self, text="Show Page 1", command=lambda: controller.show_frame(PageOne))
        button1.pack(fill="both", expand=True)

class PageOne(Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        self.label1 = Label(self, textvariable=controller.reading) # refer to Gui.reading StringVar
        self.label1.pack(fill='x')
        button1 = Button (self, text="Show Start Page", command=lambda: controller.show_frame(StartPage))
        button1.pack(fill='x')


# use .after() to simulate the update of reading variable periodically
def update_reading():
    app.reading.set(randint(0, 10000))
    print('reading:', app.reading.get())
    app.after(1000, update_reading)

app = Gui()
update_reading() # start the simulation task of updating reading variable
app.mainloop()
```

Note that I have created a function `update_reading()` to simulate the update of `reading` variable periodically using `after()` function.